# Highlight the maximum or minimum value in a flex advancedatagrid

Tags: apache-flex

I've tried and tried to do this myself but failing abysmally so hoping someone here can help.

I have an advancedatagrid that displays a table of values from an arraycollection coming from a webservice.  I am wanting to highlight either the maximum or minimum value in a row or column.

I'm not bothered how they are highlighted - be it the backround changed, the font colour changed or just making it bold - I just want that particular cell to be different to the others.

What I'm struggling with is finding the cell with the maximum (or minimum) value and then changing it's appearance.

In one grid I want to compare across the row, in another accros the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Sort the ArrayCollection using import mx.collections.Sort;

```
/* Set the ArrayCollection object's sort property and refresh the ArrayCollection. */
                arrColl.sort = numericDataSort;
                arrColl.refresh();
```

2.) Get the first item (smallest) and the last (largest) based on how you sort.

3.) Place array into AdvancedDataGrid with the property set for the two items like:

```
public function myStyleFunc(data:Object,
col:AdvancedDataGridColumn):Object
{
if (data["Artist"] == artistName)
return {color:0xFF0000};
// Return null if the Artist name does not match.
return null;
}
```

This should do it.